TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') (mongodb connection)
am trying to connect the mongodb database and i get the error as shown below
It gives me error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\server.js:22:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at cors (C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
    at C:\Users\Joh\Desktop\chipsproject\server\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:224:17

my connection file is as follow
const Express = require('express')
const app = Express()
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


var database;

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chips', (err, client)=>{
        database=client.db('chips');
        console.log('connected to database');
    })

})

app.get('/user',(request,response)=>{
    database.collection('users').find({}).toArray((err,results)=>{
        if (err) throw err

        response.send(results);
    })
})

thank youj,i will appreceate your response

I have posted my answer, please check and let me know.

You are not using the driver properly. What version of the NodeJS driver are you using? See version 6.8; MongoClient. The needed information is actually in the documentation. Construct a MongoClient with the right options and use the database on the MongoClient. If you want an answer I’ll write one but I believe the documentation should guide you.

am using  Node.js v22.3.0.


TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')

The problem is that your database variable is being accessed before  it's initialized. This happens because the connection to MongoDB is asynchronous, and your server might be handling requests before the database connection is established.
Try this instead for databse-connection.
let database;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chips')
    .then(client => {
        database = client.db('chips'); // you can also use this "client.db();"
        console.log('Connected to database');

        // Start the server only after successful DB connection
        app.listen(5000, () => {
            console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

After that you can perform rest of the database operation as per your need.
Try this,it will work.
Suggestion :-
Have you ever though that when you need database instance to other module how would you do that ?
--> Though it is my suggestion not the fixed rule,you should define database-connection to a separate module and based on your need you should import it to other module.
To know how to do that please check the below link where I have answered the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78689128/21210375

thank you brother, it worked perfect now they are communicating effectively. i struggled a whole day figuring out what was wrong with the code

@JohannesMwasanyilaJChriss , You are most welcome. Please accept the answer so that based on your approval others can take guide from it despite being downvoted.And thank you for your written confirmation.
